# Considerate pathfinding AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to have 1 wide streams of stuff be able to path-find so as to be considerate of the other stream going on the same 2 wide path.

Let's say I have a map like this: ("0"'s it cannot go, "-"'s you it can, "1" and "A" are the starting point while "2" and "b" are the destinations)

```
000000000000
0000000001A0
000000000--0
0B200------0
0--00------0
0------00000
0------00000
000000000000
```

If I have "A" path-find to "B" with the A* algorithm it would block the path from "1" to "2".("=" is the path)

```
000000000000
0000000001A0
000000000-=0
0B200======0
0=-00=-----0
0=====-00000
0------00000
000000000000
```

Yes I could path-find "1" to "2" then make the AB path but that won't always work.  Case in point is this:

```
00000000000000000000
000000000000000001A0
00000000000000000--0
0B200------00------0
0--00------00------0
0------00------00000
0------00------00000
00000000000000000000
```

The A* path-finding from "1" to "2" blocks the path for "A" to "B"

```
000000000000000001A0
00000000000000000=-0
0B200------00=====-0
0-=00=====-00=-----0
0-====-00=====-00000
0------00------00000
00000000000000000000
```

"A" to "B" blocks "1" to "2"

```
000000000000000001A0
00000000000000000-=0
0B200------00======0
0=-00=====-00=-----0
0=====-00=====-00000
0------00------00000
00000000000000000000
```

Additional Clarification:  "A", "B", "1", and "2 can be anywhere in a user created map.  There will be any number from 1 to 10 paths going at the same time and starting and stopping separately though the AI only needs to take account other current paths.  It also needs to happen live so it cannot take even seconds to compute.

So how can I make an AI smart enough to not block another path?  Right now I'm using the A* so is there an improvement to it or should I use an entirely new AI system? (both work for me)

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what algorithm you're proposing as a starting point and why it won't work in the third case. Could you clarify?

Comment: @seaotternerd  I added the explanation why the third does not work.  And the starting point algorithm though I don't care if you suggest an entirely new algorithm.

Comment: OK, so, first of all, I find your question very interesting. Then, I don't think that A* can really do what you want, except if you heavily modify it. A* focuses on finding the shortest path, but you are not interested in that, but in something different (a path that does not block another path). Are you sure you don't have additional constraints that make the problem easier? Like A is always next to 1 and B is next to 2, or something like that? Thanks

Comment: @seaotternerd No I don't think there is anything like that that's going to make it easy ):  I edited and added Additional Clarification.  Also I need this to happen live so the path cannot take even seconds to compute(Is that even possible?).

Comment: In the additional clarification, you say that there could be up to 10 paths. Is the corridor always wide enough to accommodate as many paths as there are? Also, these examples all have a corridor where you start at one end and go to the other. Will that always be the case, or can there be dead-ends, branching pathways, and the like?

Comment: @seaotternerd Branching path's yes.  Dead ends yes.  Multiple ways to get to a point yes(aka circles).  Start and destination on any different branch yes.  Always a way: **no**.

Comment: Oh wow, that's rough. This is an interesting question. I agree with Fezvez that you need something other than A*. I'll keep thinking and see if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you are searching for **Cooperative Pathfinding**. In the last decade, many solutions for this problem have been proposed. You can find a nice summary of them in [this paper](http://www.jkilavuz.com/whca/CoopPath05.pdf).

I'll give you a small recap:

- **Local Repair A**  Each agent
  searches for a route to the destination using the A* algorithm, ignoring all other agents except for its current neighbors. The agents then begin to
  follow their routes, until a collision is imminent. Whenever an agent is about to move into an occupied position it instead recalculates the remainder of its route. A bit of "brute-forcing", it is not really state of the art but it is "easy" to implement and the current industry standard in video-games. Unfortunately I'm not able to find the pseudo-code for the algorithm. :(
- **Cooperative A** s a new algorithm for solving the Co-
  operative Pathfinding problem. The task is decoupled into
  a series of single agent searches. The individual searches
  are performed in three dimensional space-time, and take account of the planned routes of other agents. A *wait* move
  is included in the agent’s action set, to enable it to remain
  stationary.
- **Hierarchical Cooperative A*** As before but in a hierarchical way.
- **Windowed Hierarchical Cooperative A*** The state of the art at the time (2005 I think). There is an interesting demo [on the internet](http://www.jkilavuz.com/whca/) with Java source code and everything. To understand why WHCA* is better go to page 3 of the paper.

I hope this can be enough to start exploring this field by yourself if you need. :)

Comment: All links in this answer now lead to dead URLs. I believe the paper is David Silver's Cooperative Pathfinding (2005) which he hosts himself: https://www.davidsilver.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/coop-path-AIIDE.pdf

I am not sure about and would be very interested in finding the demo.

Answer (score 0):

As with most problems - finding the actual constraints can help to identify the search space you are looking at.

It is not clear from the example problems if both paths can take wildly different routes or if the paths have to travel alongside each other?  Do you know if there will there always be a solution where all the paths on the map can be routed simultaneously?

If you simply require a road to support n-wide gaps ( for n parallel paths), this seems like a simple tweak to the search space/problem representation which could probably be done with A*.

Also - you have mentioned streams - is behaviour over time a dimension of the problem? - could there be an option for time-sharing (alternate use) of a narrow gap between multiple streams?  Or perhaps shorter convoys of stream elements that can path-find on their own?